# Wireless NAS - options?

Tags: nas

I want to put a NAS drive in an upstairs room (out of the way) but I believe most NAS drives need to be connected to the router. My router is hooked up close to the phone socket downstairs in a spot where we would rather just have the phone. Is there anyway to set-up a NAS drive without hooking it up directly to the router (e.g. wireless) or, better still, is there a way to move the router upstairs as well without significant recabling?

Comment: Have you already purchased a NAS drive?  If not there are wireless NAS solutions, some are very reasonable.  The MEDIAGATE MG-350HD has NDAS (a spin-off of NAS) and also has a built in FTP server and SAMBA support.  It is old school so storage capacity is limited to (IDE hard drive interface) but I have one an it does its job.  I'm sure there are other more modern solutions available too.

Answer (score 4):

Try ethernet over power:
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ethernet+over+power
I think any NAS over wireless is bad idea! You are better of using your outlet wiring as ehternet cabling.

Comment: If you opt for powerline, make sure your sockets aren't filtered

Comment: Good call - my ADSL router, wireless access point, Linux server and NAS box are upstairs and my Sony TV is downstairs, linked via a 200Mbit powerline adaptor. The server is running serviio and can stream audio and video from the NAS to the TV via the power wiring - controlled from my Android phone if I want!. Working 100% OK.

Comment: @Mat Banik why is NAS over wireless a bad idea?  Wireless is very reliable these days and it is unlikely the OP is running a high availability data center.

Comment: @typoknig: The load on the wireless hardware is to heavy and shortens the life expectancy of the device. Backup over wireless will constantly overheat the transmitter and receiver and from experience with in two year one of them will give out. And I'm talking cisco quality not your common d-link.

Comment: I've generally had bad experiences with Wireless LAN. As a means of streaming video or for backup to a NAS, the poor transfer speeds and poor reliability will come to annoy you greatly. Use wireless LAN for web browsing.

Comment: @Mat Banik I have had a lot of wireless routers and I have never had one fail because it was overloaded. My main internet connection is over a long distance (2 miles) wireless G network using 2 Linksys WRT-54G routers as a bridge. These routers have been in boxes on black roof tops for the past 5 years, typically operating at 50% load, and are still going strong. If 5 years of exposure to temperatures ranging from -10 to 110 Fahrenheit will not kill a router I don't think running near capacity for the occasional backup will either (if that is even what the OP is doing).

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Linksys WET54GS5 Wireless Ethernet Bridge with 5 Port Switch a few years ago for about $150. It's difficult to run Ethernet cables around my house, so the wireless switch has been really handy for connecting various computers without their own wireless cards to my home network. You might be able to find something similar for a lot less these days.

Comment: Ok, think I understand this. I could either go for wireless NAS or ehternet over power. With the latter would this allow me to move the router as well. Can you effectively take the ADSL cable from the phone socket and plug it directly into a ethernet over power box (connecting the router at the other end of this in another room). I basically want as much of the equipment as possible in an upstairs office. So, the router and NAS drive with access to this from pc, laptop and media player downstairs. Will this work?